# Prove that the sum $1+2+3+4+5+6+7+\ldots+n$ is never prime for $n>2$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to prove that the sum of consecutive integers $1+2+3+4+5+6+\ldots+n$ is never prime for all integers $n>2$. Here's what I tried. I assumed that the sum $1+2+3+4+5+\ldots+n=p$, where $p$ is a prime. Then $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=p$, and I can take cases from here. If $n$ is even, then we are done, because now I know that $p$ is a factor of $n+1$, a contradiction. If $n$ is odd, then $n+1$ is even and the $2$ in the denominator goes away, so I now know that $p$ is a factor of $n$, which a contradiction. Therefore, the sum is never prime.

Is there anything wrong, logically, with my attempt, like does it follow all the rules of proving things mathematically?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You mean to say $n$ is a factor of $p$, not the other way around, but otherwise it's correct.

Comment: $n(n+1)=2p$, so you need to only check two cases $n=1,n+1=2p$ and $n=2,n+1=p$, only second one gives a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to rewrite your case analysis correctly.

If $n$ is even then $p = \frac{n}{2} \cdot (n+1)$, and if $n$ is odd then $n+1$ is even and $p = n \cdot \frac{n+1}{2}$. In both cases the factors are integers $\ge 2$, contradicting that $p$ is prime.